# Injecting 2 parameters of same type

Tags: .net, autofac

I have a class with 2 parameters of same type in constructor.

I use *autofac* to inject dependencies but not able to find a way to inject 2 parameters of same type. Is there any way I can specify while injecting?

```
class test
{
    test(Iconnection con1, Iconnection con2)
    { }
}
```

I want to inject `con1` and `con2` via *autofac* but not able to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `ResolvedParameter` construct when registering your `Test` class:

```
builder.RegisterType<Test>()
       .As<ITest>()
       .WithParameter(
         new ResolvedParameter(
           (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IConnection) && pi.Name == "con1",
           (pi, ctx) => [code resolving con1 from ctx]))
       .WithParameter(
         new ResolvedParameter(
           (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IConnection) && pi.Name == "con2",
           (pi, ctx) => [code resolving con2 from ctx]));
```

Alternatively, if you're juggling differently configured instances of the same type, I'd suggest changing your constructor signature to accept a factory type (e.g. IConnectionFactory) that accepts a parameter to distinguish between connections.  For example:

```
interface IConnectionFactory
{
    IConnection CreateConnection(string name);
}
```

Comment: @user3290895 You're welcome! If this solves your problem, please go ahead and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't understand why autofac doesn't use the order specified at registration ? I mean if you already doing `.WithParametes(new [] { new TypedParameter(typeof(string), "value1"), new TypedParameter(typeof(string), "value2") }` it should pass them to the constructor such that value1 is first and value2 is second but that is not guaranteed and you get value1 twice ;/